# Get <select> attributes via PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, select, attributes

I have a  dropdown list written as follows:

```
<span class="spanClass"><input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxID" onClick="handleCheckBox()">CheckBox</label></span>
<select name="mySelect" class="mySelectClass" id="mySelectID" style="width:auto;" disabled>
   <option  value="0" <?php if($value == '0'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $string1; ?></option>
   <option  value="1" <?php if($value == '1'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $string2; ?></option>
   <option  value="2" <?php if($value == '2'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $string2; ?></option>
   <option  value="3" <?php if($value == '3'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $string3; ?></option>
   <option  value="4" <?php if($value == '4'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $string4; ?></option>
</select>
```

And I can control the "enabled" or "disabled" attribute via a Javascript function by clicking on the checkbox.

Then, I would like to get the attribute value through a PHP function.

Is possible to achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I solved in a different way.
Since I have a button which executes another JS function which executes another PHP code, I check if the checkbox is checked or not, so I can control the values from this function.

Bye

Comment: which attribute value?

Comment: I want to know if the <select> "mySelect" is disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get che selected value in an option tag in JS you can do it with Jquery in a very simple way:

`$( "#mySelectID" ).val();`

if you want the text of the selected value you can use something like:

```
$( "#mySelectID option:selected" ).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

possible error when you are doing it with php is that, you are trying to assign `selected` value  of the select for more than one option.

Since there conditions

```
<?php if($value == '1'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>
<?php if($value == '2'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>
<?php if($value == '3'){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>
```

and more than one condition can be true, and in such a case we may not be able to decide which is the selected option.

Comment: a variable like `$value` can't have multiple values, so there will only be one `<option>` with the `selected` tag